filtering websocket traffic in Apache proxy
I have a non-Internet-connected IoT device that I need to give access to over the Internet; I have set up an access-controlled Apache proxy for it that's working fine.
The challenge is that, as a typical IoT device, its web interface has no way to let someone read its data without also being able to change its settings (accidentally or intentionally).
The problem is that its web interface is a websockets app, so even though the proxy is working fine (after figuring out how to proxy websockets, which was a special bundle of fun) the 'Location' directives I put in to keep the user out of the dangerous parts of the site don't have any effect since the browser is just pretending to be going to URLs like "/configuration" but all those calls are actually happening inside the websockets tunnel.
So: does anyone know of a way to filter the activity inside a websockets proxy?  Preferably in Apache, but frankly this is annoying enough that I'd use pretty much any open source proxy at this point.
(DuckDuckGo and Google seem to have no results pertaining to filtering websockets activity at all, which shocked the heck out of me.)

The only thing that could do something like what I need that I could find is https://github.com/sensepost/wsproxy, a 7-years old node.js app for running man-in-the-middle attacks on websocket apps.  I was able to adapt that (via a totally barbaric hatchet-job on the codebase) into a service that sits between Apache's proxy server and my IoT device which simply drops requests for sections of the app that I want to exclude.  So, it's kinda solved but more elegant solutions would still be welcome.  :-)
